# Is there a language with Don Knuth's up arrow notation?

Tags: math

Is there any programming language that has [Don Knuth's up arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) as a built in operator?

Comment: Mathematica. (http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpArrow.html) Also has `ack` as the generalized Ackermann function.

Comment: @Hugh then post it as an answer! :)

Comment: Seems like it has no built-in meaning. So it doesn't evaluate. It should be `PowerTower`. I'll post as an answer when I've confirmed it.